# unlinking android mobile from google play store

Tags: google-play-store

I have 2 android mobiles and now I'm not using one of them.Is it possible to unlink the mobile which I'm not using from the Google play store?

Answer (score 0):

I would preform a factory reset. This will erase the Google account from the phone and it will erase all of your user data. This way if it gets lost/stolen or you want to give it away it is good to go!

To do a factory reset it is basically the same for all devices:

> Settings Menu --> Privacy --> Factory Reset --> Confirm...

Comment: Half good to go: unless you safe-erase it, content might still be restored. Besides, the question was not to reset the phone -- which even after that would still be listed in "My Devices" on Google Play, so that would not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to completely unlink devices listed under on the Google Play website. However, if you'd prefer to hide or remove a device from view, you can do so:

1. Visit [play.google.com/settings](https://play.google.com/settings)
2. Untick the checkbox next to the device(s) you wish to hide

[Source](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2407656?hl=en)